# How to implement a UICollectionVIew with multiple cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, custom-cell

I have two cells to be included in single collectionview. They are added in a zig zag way as shown in figure. Can anyone help?[image]

Answer (score 1):

To show images in zigzag manner you need to create custom view.
You will get some information from

1. https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/
2. http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-creating-custom-layouts-uicollectionview/
3. https://maniacdev.com/2013/06/uicollectionview-layout-that-automatically-organizes-things-in-a-linear-manner-based-on-content-size